# Installing non-native RPM in Centos 6.6

Tags: centos, rpm, dependencies

I'm trying to install gstreamer0.10-pocketsphinx on Centos 6.6. Apparently no one in the history of the Internet has ever wanted to do this before so there is very little out there for Centos in particular, only for Ubuntu and Debian which is not helpful. Unfortunately yum does not have anything PocketSphinx or SphinxBase related so I am trying to install via the RPM: gstreamer0.10-pocketsphinx-0.8-7.mga5.x86_64.rpm

I run:

```
rpm -Uvh gstreamer0.10-pocketsphinx-0.8-7.mga5.x86_64.rpm
```

And it tells me it is missing dependencies (which I have already installed):

```
    warning: gstreamer0.10-pocketsphinx-0.8-7.mga5.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 80420f66: NOKEY
    error: Failed dependencies:
        libpocketsphinx.so.1()(64bit) is needed by gstreamer0.10-pocketsphinx-0.8-7.mga5.x86_64
        libsphinxbase.so.1()(64bit) is needed by gstreamer0.10-pocketsphinx-0.8-7.mga5.x86_64
        pocketsphinx = 0.8-7.mga5 is needed by gstreamer0.10-pocketsphinx-0.8-7.mga5.x86_64
```

The files libpocketsphinx.so.1, libsphinxbase.so.1 are installed in /usr/local/lib

Pocketsphinx is installed elsewhere (located in /progs/pocketsphinx-0.8).

This all being the case, how do I tell the RPM where the dependencies are on my system? I've looked around quite a bit and haven't found anything, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: If you don't install the needed libraries as rpm package indicating what they provide, `yum`/`rpm` won't find them, as it just looks up it's own database of installed stuff. You can force `rpm` to skip the dependency check with `--nodeps`, but it's your job to make sure the needed stuff is found afterwards - in other words, I would not do that.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. So if I force an installation and ignore the dependencies, will the installed software be of any use or will it also not know where to find the dependencies?

Comment: That does sound like it would be pretty useless. Any other way to do it? Or am I just out of luck?

Comment: Also forgot to mention I can't find the source anywhere just RPMs and DEBs or I would just install manually.

Comment: This sounds like a lot  of quite esoteric stuff - what use does it have on a production server?

Comment: Office-wide voice recognition with later integration with Asterisk

Comment: Well, if you don't get a complete package, I would rather build my own. The source can be found at Sourceforge: http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/download/

Comment: Thanks! Good suggestion. I will do so. I still have the source from my original SphinxBase and PocketSphinx installations. If I get it right I will post it somewhere and put a link here for all the other weirdos (if there are any) that want to run PocketSphinx with Gstreamer on Centos.

Comment: Might I suggest you try Fedora, which has pocketsphinx and the gstreamer plugin (`yum install pocketsphinx-plugin`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

either find a RPM package providing

```
 libpocketsphinx.so.1, libsphinxbase.so.1
```

Or you you can create a custom rpm which provides the necessary dependencies, just to keep rpm happy, or finally you could install  gstreamer0.10-pocketsphinx  using `rpm` with the `--force` flag.